# Building an array with indefinite dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to build an array of arrays with indefinite number of dimensions.

How could I:

- Get the number of dimensions of the parent array
- Cycle through the outermost dimension elements

I know this might be a stupid question but I am a newbie in javascript so please guide me.

[Edit]

The project that I'm working on is something that will generate html code (to be used in a certain application). I will ask the user to input rows and columns( columns are nested under each other according to order ).

example:

```
Rows = a,b,c
col1 = q,w,e
col2 = 1,2,3

It would generate a table like this:
| rows |  q  |  w  |  e  |
|      |1|2|3|1|2|3|1|2|3|
|  a   |x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|
|  b   |x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|
|  c   |x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|
```

But some custom functions are being asked (like merged cells, hiding a column, etc..) so I plan to make a nested array that will hold the columns.

Comment: Can you give a code snippet of what you are trying to do?

Comment: JavaScript Arrays aren't multi-dimensional, though they can be nested to give a similar effect. You can't find out how deeply nested without traversal into the nested arrays.

Comment: am not i am +1, plus take little time to understand what is a JS Array, you won't regret it! http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info guys, I thought JS Arrays could be multi-dimensional, so the only way is to traverse into nested arrays to find how many levels it is nested. As for the code snippet, I don't have it yet as I'm still trying to figure out how to do it. But will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to iterate through an array of arrays that is not square. You can get the .length property at each index of the outer array to get the inner dimension.

```
var one = [1];
var two = [1,1];
var three = [1,1,1];
var four = [1,1,1,1];
var five = [1,1,1,1,1];

var container = [one,two,three,four,five];
$("#outer").html(container.length);

for(var i =0; i < container.length; i++){
     $("#inner").append(container[i].length + ',');   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPwrn/ - running example

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but I think I have to use that for loop in a recursive function to get all the levels.

Answer (score 0):

Java script arrays are not multi-dimensional, By the way you can create array of arrays to achieve the same.

```
var xArrays = [[],[],[]];
```

Though they are not multi-dimensional, they can resize at any point.

```
xArrays.push([]);  xArrays[xArrays.length]=[]; //adding an array
xArrays.pop(); //removing an array
```

Traversing through an array,

```
xArray.forEach(
        function(xTemp){ 
            alert(xTemp.length); //You can do your inner level iterations here. 
                      });
```